# sendmail command to send an email with txt file attachment

Tags: linux, email, unix, sendmail

I am trying to send email from Perl script using `sendmail` command.

Email contains a attachment (.txt file).

Here is the command I have tried:

```
>:/usr/people/vkk > echo "Subject:Report" | sendmail -t vkk@test.com < "/usr/people/vkk/Downloads/report_daily_2022_08_24_19_30_17.txt"
Ambiguous input redirect.
```

When I add `echo "Subject:Report"` option it gives following message -

> Ambiguous input redirect

What is the right syntax to send an email with an attachment and subject line using `sendmail` command.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a good idea to send an attachment using sendmail command because you have to encoded the attachment by uuencode. So it is better to use mail or mutt command to sending attachment. Below command is the example for mail command.

## echo "Message Body" | mail -s "Subject Line" -a attachment.txt email@domain

Install mail command in Centos/RHEL

## sudo yum install mailx

Install mail command on Ubuntu/Debian/LinuxMint

## sudo apt-get install mailutils

Comment: mail should be installed properly to avoid "mail: cannot send message: Broken pipe" error